# How to get a command variable inside another command variable?

Tags: bash, shell

Example here:

```sh
gitrepo=$(jq -r '.gitrepo' 0.json)
releasetag=$(curl --silent ""https://api.github.com/repos/\"$gitrepo\""/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name":' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/')
echo "$releasetag"
```

Used `\"` to escape characters.

0.json:

```json
{
        "type": "github-releases",
        "gitrepo": "ipfs/go-ipfs"
}
```

How to put $gitrepo to work inside $releasetag?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variables expand inside quoted `"` strings.

```sh
gitrepo="$(jq -r '.gitrepo' 0.json)"
releasetag="$(
  curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$gitrepo/releases/latest" \
  | grep '"tag_name":' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'
)"
echo "$releasetag"
```

Btw, as you are using `jq` to extract `.gitrepo` from `0.json`, you could also use it in the exact same way to extract `.tag_name` from `curl`'s output (instead  of using `grep` and `sed`) like so:

```sh
gitrepo="$(jq -r '.gitrepo' 0.json)"
releasetag="$(
  curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$gitrepo/releases/latest" \
  | jq -r '.tag_name'
)"
echo "$releasetag"
```

And to simplify it even further (depending on your use case), just write:

```sh
curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/$(jq -r '.gitrepo' 0.json)/releases/latest" \
| jq -r '.tag_name'
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do you have a GitHub acc? I would like to add thanks

Comment: No, I haven't but I appreciate it. :)